# SSIS packages processing data from an excel file

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a SSIS script that processes data from an Excel file coming from a third party. The only issue I have is there's a column with the customer's names in that file, and when a name contains a special character like `'`, the code will not process that file.

How could it be modified to allow a special character such as an aposthropy (`'`)?

Comment: Does an error occur when processing the file? If yes, can you edit your answer to include the error?

Comment: It just says, that the file failed to load.